# How to get programmatically System On Chip data from device

Tags: android, processor, soc

I want to get the complete processor name of an programmatic manner, like CPU-Z app does. E.g: Qualcomm Snapdragon 800. The last one is the most important information for me, i.e, 800.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [How to get specific information of an Android device from “/proc/cpuinfo” flie?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239956/how-to-get-specific-information-of-an-android-device-from-proc-cpuinfo-flie)

Comment: When I run the command from the above comment (adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo) on my device I get `Hardware : SAMSUNG Exynos7420`. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: This question is too broad. Please help me create CPUZ is not a good question and should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

> ...like CPU-Z app does. E.g: Qualcomm Snapdragon 800. The last one is the most important information for me, i.e, 800.

@WeybkbcOTHER I'll probably disappoint you, but the kind of information you're trying to get is indeed kernel-specific. In the broad market of Android devices vendors use a vast variety of the last. And if the `CPU-Z` app shows a desired information for one device, it does not mean it would be same informative for another one. Again, such information is device(kernel)-specific.

> I want to get the complete processor name of an programmatic manner...

The most important part of the `Androd` OS, or more precisely `Linux`, you can get this kind of info from is the `/proc` pseudo-filesystem. The "filesystem" provides a directory-based view of processes running in the system along with **system-wide diagnostics**, like processor info (again, you can't rely on completeness of information to be provided!). Strictly speaking, `/proc` is the "one of the closest (lower) points of a device CPU info".

Regarding the "programmatic manner", note that when deriving the info from the `/proc` "filesystem" you will have to deal with parsing its entries that you'd poll.

Below is a couple of examples of important `/proc` entries (used with commands) that you may (or may not - depending on vendor supply) use for deriving the CPU info:

- `cat /proc/cpuinfo` of course, where you might find a CPU family and, if any, name (under the `Hardware` key);
- `cat /proc/stat`, where you can investigate the number of CPU cores (denoted as `cpux` where `x` is numerated in accordance to the cores number);

*Recommended reading*: [Android Internals::Power User's View by Jonathan Levin](http://newandroidbook.com/AIvI-M-RL1.pdf).