# How do I detect CPU and Memory usage on android using Appcelerator?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-studio

I'm trying to detect the CPU speed, Usage Percentage, Memory, Memory usage in the Android device while using the app.
The application is being created in Appcelerator Studio.
I have read that I need to parse /proc/cpuinfo but I have no idea how to even detect the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the JAVA code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26242139/5193915 and use Hyperloop to access it. The module list at http://gitt.io/search?q=cpu doesn't list any module